# Explanation Static Members

Tags: c#, string, class

Why Class1.a is still null even if I referenced it and change its value? Strings are reference type so I think that changing is value will affect the reference but it's not true. Someone can explain me why? It's for the static declarator?

```
class Class1
{
    public static string a;
}
void Main()
{
    string a = Class1.a;
    a = "hello";
    MessageBox.Show(Class1.a);
}
```

> Output: null

Comment: `MessageBox.Show(a)`

Comment: Class1.a = "hello";

Comment: Because both are different strings

Comment: More like "explanation of reference type variables"...

Comment: You are assigning a reference to a new string to `a`, not mutating the reference it points at when you do `a = "hello";`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You didn't change its value. You just made a copy of the null reference into a local variable, you set the local variable to refer to a new string, but in all of that you never changed the original reference to refer to anything other than null.

It's true that strings are a reference type, but even with reference types, changing the reference itself is different than changing a property on the object being referenced.

For example:

```
Foo a = new Foo ();
Foo b = a;
b.Bar = 7;
b = new Foo ();
b.Baz = 12;
```

In this example, a.Bar will be 7, since at the time a and b referenced the same object. However, a.Baz was not set to 12, because b was changed to refer to a different object. The variable a also still refers to the first object created, not the second.

String additionally doesn't let you modify the object (it is immutable), but that is an aside - the reason your code doesn't work is because you were modifying the reference, not modifying the object.

Answer (score 0):

In `Main()`, when you write `a = "hello";`, you are telling the local reference variable `a` to refer to a different string. (Previously in your writing `string a = Class1.a;` it was referring to the same string as `Class1.a`).

The new value of `a` will then, in general, be a different string to the one referred to the `static` member of `Class1`.

Answer (score -1):

Static fields are associated with types rather than objects this is why they share same storage even with **multiple instances** i.e. regardless of how many object you create and its easy to be confused with. Regardless of static its more how references works

So your assignment i.e. 
`string a = Class1.a;` a just has value of reference from Class1.a which is null, however on second line `a = "hello";` you are changing that to something else which reference points to data `"hello"` but here Class1.a is still referencing to null.

Not directly but indirectly this reference might help you: http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/parameters.html

Comment: This in no way explains why editing the local doesn't affect the static field, which is what the question is asking.

Comment: @Servy if it would, it would defeat purpose of having static field

Comment: It would defeat the purpose of having a shared storage if multiple instances would be able to affect it?  No, that's not how that works.  Creating a local variable that aliases a static field wouldn't defeat the purpose of having a static field.  This doesn't do that, but that is by no means *why* it doesn't do that.

Comment: @Servy could you check my edits?